# Writing a shell script to compile and dispatch my server program?

Tags: linux, shell, svn, server, qmake

I am new to linux programming. I recently wanted to write a shell script which could greatly help myself in compiling and dispatch my server program.

Basically, the script should get a svn-repository revison (eg. codesample-svn-120) from my SVN server

and compile the project automatically using QMAKE. Further more, the script will zip the executables and upload the .zip file to a remote server.

I wonder where could I find such tutorials or code samples so I can make sense of my goal.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

If you know the commands to do what you need, then edit a file called `my_first_script.sh`, then put a *shebang*

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and put all the commands you need after. The script will execute line by lines until the end.

You will need to :

```
chmod +x my_first_script.sh
```

and to run it :

```
./my_first_script.sh
```

Comment: Hi, sputnick, thanks for answering, I can do these mannually. So, what I need to do is reading a "Intro to shell programming "?

Comment: Up2you, but here you just have to put you commands + some `cd somewhere`, it's pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about shell script(Bash) here http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html